# Combinar dos querys en uno usando SQL

Tags: datatables, sql, select, report

quisiera ver la forma de combinar dos querys en uno

estos serial mis dos queris, son diferente tabla pero son similares en los datos

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 530 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Assy ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 530 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Assy NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 170 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Disco ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 170 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Disco NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 410 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Linea_Rim ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 410 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Rim NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 790 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Linea_ED ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 790 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_ED NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1020 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO TC ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1020 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO TC NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 840 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'RRO ED ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 840 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO ED NG',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1420 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_GP12 ok',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1420 AND Rejected = 1 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_GP12 NG'
FROM Part_v_Production_e A1
INNER JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Record_Date)  BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL
    AND ISNULL(A1.Quantity,0)>0
```

query 2

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 530 OR B1.Operation_No = 570 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Assy SCRAP',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 170 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Disco',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 490 OR B1.Operation_No = 410 OR B1.Operation_No = 300 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Rim',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 790 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_ED',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1020 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO TC',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 840 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO ED',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1420 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_GP12'
FROM Part_v_Scrap_e A1
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Scrap_Date)   BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL AND ISNULL(A1.Quantity,0)>0
```

Comment: Y que quiere decir combinarlas?

Comment: tener los datos de los dos query en uno solo query

Comment: Y con union? no sirve?

Comment: Igual, deberias igualar las columnas para poder poner uno bajo el otro...